# SQL case expression on date variable

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to adjust some SQL to change the date if its a Monday. If the date is Monday then I would like to set the @date variable to the previous Friday, else set the @date variable to today -1.

Below is what I currently have, which works fine on all days except Monday where it sets @date to Sunday, is there anyway I can add a case statement to say that if its a Monday then use -3 instead of -1 days.

```
declare @date varchar(10)
select  @date = CONVERT(varchar(10), getdate()-1, 101)
print @date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date VARCHAR(10)

SELECT @date = CONVERT(varchar(10), 
                       DATEADD(day, 
                               CASE 
                                   -- If today is Monday, set the offset to -3 days (previous Friday)
                                   WHEN DATEPART(dw, GETDATE()) = 2 THEN -3  
                                   -- For all other days, set the offset to -1 day (yesterday)
                                   ELSE -1  
                               END, 
                               GETDATE()), 
                       101)

PRINT @date
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/3-X-iHjw

Comment: A *good* answer explains the solution.

Comment: Also `DATEPART` will vary by locale setting; you don't address that.

Comment: Why use an if statement when you can inline a case expression?

Comment: @DaleK yes you are right I hhave updated my answer with CASE instead of IF Statement

Comment: I get the wrong date: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/RNnxmCPM)

Comment: The issue might be related to the DATEFIRST setting in your SQL Server instance.
you can explicitly set the DATEFIRST to 7 (Sunday) at the beginning of your script.
like : https://dbfiddle.uk/trJfjh_6

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-datefirst-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: The fact that you, or CrapGPT, missed the point cements my point. You can't expect people to change their date settings at the start of every connection.